# How to change the folder name of a PrestaShop module?

Tags: prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I need change folder name on FTP of one of modules in PrestaShop 1.7. Where in database or any files of PrestaShop I should rewrite this change?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the following:

1. First, uninstall the module from the PrestaShop Admin Panel
2. Then, rename the module's folder via FTP
3. Then, make sure you also rename the main module file inside the module's folder
4. Lastly, edit this file, and make sure you update the module's name and class name
5. Re-install the module

Voilà! By proceeding this way, you don't have to make any changes in database.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but I can not use this easy way. There is a lot of customization of this module and lot of custom hooks. I just need a change the folder name. Can you give me an advice?

Comment: If you follow my recommendation, you won't have to make any changes to your hooks, just to the module's name and filename.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no install zip for this module, as I mentioned, there are many customization directly in files. Only way is rename folder directly, but I need to connect PrestaShop to the renamed folder, can you give me any advice how to do it by this way? Thank you.

Comment: Even with your customizations it should work, there are no changes to make in database if this folder isn’t related to a « real » module which can be installed/uninstalled.

Comment: I would like to do it manually - rename folder via FTP and manually make changes in database or any other files if needed. Without uninstall the module. Do you know, where I should make the changes?